# iOS - Converting a UIImage to vImage memory handling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiimage, accelerate-framework

I have a function where I convert a `UIImage` to a `vImage` (to be used in some `vImage` methods in iOS's `Accelerate.framework`.

The method I have is:

```
-(vImage_Buffer)convertImage:(UIImage *)image {
    CGImageRef sourceRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger sourceWidth = CGImageGetWidth(sourceRef);
    NSUInteger sourceHeight = CGImageGetHeight(sourceRef);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    unsigned char *sourceData = (unsigned char*)calloc(sourceHeight * sourceWidth * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger sourceBytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * sourceWidth;
    NSUInteger bitsPerComponent = 8;
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(sourceData, sourceWidth, sourceHeight,
                                                       bitsPerComponent, sourceBytesPerRow, colorSpace,
                                                       kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, sourceWidth, sourceHeight), sourceRef);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    vImage_Buffer v_image = {
        .data = sourceData,
        .height = sourceHeight,
        .width = sourceWidth,
        .rowBytes = sourceBytesPerRow
    };

    return v_image;
}
```

I built this by mix and matching a few code snippets on the web.

**My question is,** I have a `calloc` call which allocates the space for `sourceData`. But how, and where would I free this memory?

Given that I may call this method many times, it seems like *as-is*, there would be a huge memory leak. I don't think I would release it here because it supplies the backing `.data` for my `vImage_Buffer` variable. But then would I release it in my calling function? Or would setting `v_image` to `nil` (*or whatever the returned variable is named in the calling method*) ultimately release the memory allocated by the `calloc` line?

Does anyone have any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all You also need to release `colorSpace` by calling `CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace)`

Memory allocated by `calloc` can later be released in calling function using `free(v_image.data)` (*or whatever the returned variable is named in the calling method*).

You can also change Your method implementation to get rid of `CGContext` and get bytes from `CGImage` using `CGDataProviderRef` it would be something like:

```
-(vImage_Buffer)convertImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    CGImageRef sourceRef = [image CGImage];
    NSUInteger sourceWidth = CGImageGetWidth(sourceRef);
    NSUInteger sourceHeight = CGImageGetHeight(sourceRef);

    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(sourceRef);
    CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);

    unsigned char *sourceData = (unsigned char*)calloc(sourceHeight * sourceWidth * 4, sizeof(unsigned char));
    NSUInteger bytesPerPixel = 4;
    NSUInteger sourceBytesPerRow = bytesPerPixel * sourceWidth;

    CFDataGetBytes(bitmapData, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(bitmapData)), sourceData);

    vImage_Buffer v_image = {
        .data = (void *)sourceData,
        .height = sourceHeight,
        .width = sourceWidth,
        .rowBytes = sourceBytesPerRow
    };

    CFRelease(bitmapData);

    return v_image;
}
```

However I didn't check the performance.

I'd also suggest to rename Your method to something like `vImageCreateFromImage`. You'll be aware that later You are responsible of cleaning up the memory.

Answer (score 2):

First, and most importantly, this was greatly simplified in iOS7.0 / OSX 10.9, with the introduction of the `vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage` function (declared in vImage_Utilities.h, with fairly extensive documentation in the header).  If you don't need to support older OSes, you should consider using this new function.

Second, whether you use your existing code or `InitWithCGImage`, once you are done using a `vImage_Buffer` object created by either means, you should free the memory associated with the data field: `free(buffer.data);`.

Comment: A CGBitmapContext is both an export mechanism and drawing surface. The need to keep the drawing surface complexity to a minimum means it isn't very flexible about what sorts of formats it can produce. This is one of the reasons vImageBuffer_InitWithCGImage was added. It gives you facile access to nearly any CG compatible image format you might want (and a few more).